# Spring MVC async method (RXJava)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, rx-java

EDIT: my answer is below

I have a specific scenario that I could use a little guidance on.  I have a POST endpoint that I'd like to call some async methods (that I don't care about the results of, so they're void), and return to the user immediately.  For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity subscribe(@RequestBody SomePayload payload) {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> someService.longRunningVoidMethod(payload));
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Is there a way to do this using RXJava (the API I'm working on uses RXJava, so I'd like to follow the same patterns as the rest of it)?  Like, an Observable that doesn't emit anything?  I'm very new to RXJava so I'm reaching out for some more specific advice that I'm struggling to find reading on my own.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity subscribe(@RequestBody SomePayload payload) {
    Completable.fromAction(() -> someService.longRunningVoidMethod(payload))
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
           .subscribe();
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I guess .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) makes the function execute on a background task and not wait for it to complete before moving on.

Answer (score 0):

Use *Completable* if you are not interested in result. *Single* if you expect strictly 1 result. *Observable* in all other cases.

```java
Completable.fromFuture(future).subscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks, taking me down the Completable rabbit hole lead me to finding the Schedulers, which seems to be used for thread manipulation.